# Фиксированное меню css

Tags: html, css

Возникла небольшая проблема, нужно сделать фиксированное меню, чтобы при прокрутке оно оставалось на месте. С помощью `position: fixed` выходит беда, ширина перестаёт быть зависимой от `.box`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: url(../source/bg.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.box {
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: auto;
  height: 2000px;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 900px;
  min-width: 700px;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: #c3deee;
}

nav div {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-table;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  color: #fff;
}

nav div a {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: 24px "Lucida Console", Arial, sans-serif;
  color: inherit;
}

nav div:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <!-- Меню -->
  <nav>
    <div><a>Главная</a></div>
    <div><a>Мероприятия</a></div>
    <div><a>О городе</a></div>
    <div><a>Маршруты</a></div>
  </nav>
  <!-- Слайдер -->
  <div class="slider">
  </div>
  <!-- Основное -->
  <div class="content">
  </div>
  <!-- Ноги -->
  <footer>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно задать вашему nav:

```
nav {
  height: 60px;
  background: #c3deee;
  position:fixed;  
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 900px;
  min-width: 700px;
}
```

Ровно как и у вашего бокса. Они независимо друг от друга просто будут иметь одинаковую ширину. Можно убедиться [Здесь (JsFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/gfvm5ex2/), меняя размер окна с результатом.

Answer (score 2):

Добавил `nav` `position: fixed` и `max-width: inherit`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: url(../source/bg.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.box {
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: auto;
  height: 2000px;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 900px;
  min-width: 700px;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: #c3deee;
  position: fixed;
  max-width: inherit;
}

nav div {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-table;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  color: #fff;
}

nav div a {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: 24px "Lucida Console", Arial, sans-serif;
  color: inherit;
}

nav div:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <!-- Меню -->
  <nav>
    <div><a>Главная</a></div>
    <div><a>Мероприятия</a></div>
    <div><a>О городе</a></div>
    <div><a>Маршруты</a></div>
  </nav>
  <!-- Слайдер -->
  <div class="slider">
  </div>
  <!-- Основное -->
  <div class="content">
  </div>
  <!-- Ноги -->
  <footer>
  </footer>
</div>
```